# detectar form abierto y cerrar dicho form

Tags: c#, windows-forms

espero me puedan ayudar.

lo que quiero hacer es detectar un form que esta dentro de mi proyecto, una ves que se haya detectado el form, cerrar dicho form, para detectar el form que quiero cerrar uso el siguiente codigo

```
foreach (Form frm in Application.OpenForms)
                {
                    if (frm.GetType() == typeof(form_tabla))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("from abierto");
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

ahora una ves detectado lo que quiero es cerrarlo,espero me puedan ayudar, gracias

Comment: Puedes agregar que error que te lanza y aclarar porque quieres cerrar las ventanas con un bucle for? así podremos darte una mejor respuesta.

Comment: También explica para que utilizar esta comparación `if(frm.GetType() == typeof(form_tabla))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para cerrar el formulario activo puedes hacerlo de este modo.

```
//Almacena una instancia del formulario activo.
Form currentForm = Form.ActiveForm;

//Sierra el formulario
currentForm.Close();
```

Si lo que quieres es cerrarlos todos

```
Environment.Exit(1);
```

De todas formas, si lo quieres hacer por un bucle, debes utilizar este código.

```
FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;

foreach (Form frm in fc)
{
    //código aquí... 
    frm.Close();
}
```

No te recomiendo este método, al menos que quieras hacer, algo más, aparte de cerrar los formularios abiertos.

Puedes ver mas información en la [documentación](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.form.activeform(v=vs.110).aspx) de microsoft.

Espero te aya sido de utilidad.

Comment: Buen dia!! gracias por el apoyo, ya intente hacer eso pero a un así no me sale, me marca error:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault se debe llamar antes de crear el primer objeto IWin32Window en la aplicación.'

no se a que se refiere

Comment: Primero donde empleas este código y que código utilizaste para que te diera este error? ya que a mi no me sale este error.

Answer (score 2):

Si en `frm` encuentras correctamente el formulario que buscas, simplemente haz `frm.Close()`:

```
foreach (Form frm in Application.OpenForms)
{
       if (frm.GetType() == typeof(form_tabla))
       {
             frm.Close();
             break;
       }
}
```

Otra opción es usar LINQ y te evitas el bucle:

```
var frm=Application.OpenForms.OfType<form_tabla>().FirstOrDefault();
if (frm!=null) frm.Close();
```

Comment: buen dia!! gracias por el apoyo, ya intente también con este método pero no me sale, seria posible que me apoyaras con un ejemplo mas de favor

Comment: @Daniel que significa _no me sale_? no te lo cierra? te da algún error?

Comment: @Daniel Deberías poner mas de el código. Porque el error seguramente es en otra parte.

Comment: el código que me pasaste esta bien, a ver si me doy a explicar mejor, tengo 3 clases:

-clase padre
-clase hijo
-clase subhijo "sub-clase"

de la clase padre llamo a la clase hijo(es esta clase "hijo" tengo la opcion para abrir y cerrar la ventana subhijo),y de la clase hijo llamo a la clase subhijo, entonces de la clase padre cierro la clase hijo, pero la clase sub-hijo sigue activa, entonces cuando regreso a la clase hijo para cerrar la ventana ya no puedo, por eso uso ese codigo, por que ese detecta la clase subhijo pero no se como cerrarla